# Hadoop HA Namenode remote access

Tags: hadoop, remote-access, high-availability, nameservice

Im configuring Hadoop 2.2.0 stable release with HA namenode but i dont know how to configure remote access to the cluster.

I have HA namenode configured with manual failover and i defined `dfs.nameservices` and i can access hdfs with nameservice from all the nodes included in the cluster, but not from outside.

I can  perform operations on hdfs by contact directly the active namenode, but i dont want that, i want to contact the cluster and then be redirected to the active namenode. I think this is the normal configuration for a HA cluster.

Does anyone now how to do that?

(thanks in advance...)

Comment: On your client node, have you configured core-site.xml with the appropriate properties (fs.default.name for the cluster name, and ha.zookeeper.quorum for the list of ZK servers)? Can you post your current core-site.xml back into your original question.

Comment: i am accessing hdfs via webHDFS so i don't have hadoop installed on my client node.

Comment: no one have an opinion to share about this question?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648214/any-command-to-get-active-namenode-for-nameservice-in-hadoop for info on how to figure out which is the active namenode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact one of the Name nodes (as you're currently doing) - there is no cluster node to contact.

The hadoop client code knows the address of the two namenodes (in core-site.xml) and can identity which is the active and which is the standby. There might be a way by which you can interrogate a zookeeper node in the quorum to identify the active / standby (maybe, i'm not sure) but you might as well check one of the namenodes - you have a 50/50 chance it's the active one.

I'd have to check, but you might be able to query either if you're just reading from HDFS.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the reply. Im using pywebhdfs, so he don't use the core-site.xml file. What I'm doing is... store the two namenode addresses. If an operation fails, i look on the exception for the "Standbyexception", if exists, i try the other namenode...

Answer (score 2):

You have to add more values to the hdfs site:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.myns</name>
    <value>machine-98,machine-99</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.myns.machine-98</name>
    <value>machine-98:8100</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.myns.machine-99</name>
    <value>machine-145:8100</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.myns.machine-98</name>
    <value>machine-98:50070</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.myns.machine-99</name>
    <value>machine-145:50070</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

for Active Name node you can always ask Zookeeper.
you can get the active name node from the below Zk Path.

```
/hadoop-ha/namenodelogicalname/ActiveStandbyElectorLock
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to resolve this situation(code with java)

1. use core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml in your code

   [load conf via addResource](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#addResource(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path))
2. use conf.set in your code

   [set hadoop conf via conf.set](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#set(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

   [an example use conf.set](https://gist.github.com/lurenx/0977228fc52243702fdff6462b840e8e)