# Any command to get active namenode for nameservice in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, high-availability, hadoop-yarn

The command:

```
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState machine-98
```

Works only if you know the machine name. Is there any command like:

```
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState <nameservice>
```

which can tell you the IP/hostname of the **active** namenode?

Comment: +1: Good question. The answer is `no` most probably. Even without HA, there is no command to show the namenode's hostname/ip ASFAIK. `hdfs dfsadmin -report` shows only datanodes. There are workarounds however.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To print out the namenodes use this command:

```
hdfs getconf -namenodes
```

To print out the secondary namenodes:

```
hdfs getconf -secondaryNameNodes
```

To print out the backup namenodes:

```
hdfs getconf -backupNodes
```

Note: These commands were tested using Hadoop 2.4.0.

**Update** 10-31-2014:

Here is a python script that will read the NameNodes involved in Hadoop HA from the config file and determine which of them is active by using the hdfs haadmin command. This script is not fully tested as I do not have HA configured. Only tested the parsing using a sample file based on the Hadoop HA Documentation. Feel free to use and modify as needed.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: UTF-8
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import subprocess as SP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hdfsSiteConfigFile = "/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"

    tree = ET.parse(hdfsSiteConfigFile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    hasHadoopHAElement = False
    activeNameNode = None
    for property in root:
        if "dfs.ha.namenodes" in property.find("name").text:
            hasHadoopHAElement = True
            nameserviceId = property.find("name").text[len("dfs.ha.namenodes")+1:]
            nameNodes = property.find("value").text.split(",")
            for node in nameNodes:
                #get the namenode machine address then check if it is active node
                for n in root:
                    prefix = "dfs.namenode.rpc-address." + nameserviceId + "."
                    elementText = n.find("name").text
                    if prefix in elementText:
                        nodeAddress = n.find("value").text.split(":")[0]                

                        args = ["hdfs haadmin -getServiceState " + node]  
                        p = SP.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=SP.PIPE, stderr=SP.PIPE)

                        for line in p.stdout.readlines():
                            if "active" in line.lower():
                                print "Active NameNode: " + node
                                break;
                        for err in p.stderr.readlines():
                            print "Error executing Hadoop HA command: ",err
            break            
    if not hasHadoopHAElement:
        print "Hadoop High-Availability configuration not found!"
```

Comment: Ah this will not tell me the active namenode, will it?

Comment: @Dragonborn I missed the part about HA being used. Answer updated with a python script to parse the hdfs config and run the haadmin command against each machine. script will report which is active.

Comment: +1 to teach a new command. But they should've provided a direct way for this. Even a `*` after the active namenode's name will be sufficient.

Answer (score 16):

Found this:

https://gist.github.com/cnauroth/7ff52e9f80e7d856ddb3

This works out of the box on my CDH5 namenodes, although I'm not sure other hadoop distributions will have http://namenode:50070/jmx available - if not, I think it can be added by deploying [Jolokia](http://jolokia.org).

Example:

```
curl 'http://namenode1.example.com:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'
{
  "beans" : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
    "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
    "State" : "active",
    "NNRole" : "NameNode",
    "HostAndPort" : "namenode1.example.com:8020",
    "SecurityEnabled" : true,
    "LastHATransitionTime" : 1436283324548
  } ]
```

So by firing off one http request to each namenode (this should be quick) we can figure out which one is the active one.

It's also worth noting that if you talk [WebHDFS REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) to an inactive namenode you will get a 403 Forbidden and the following JSON:

```
{"RemoteException":{"exception":"StandbyException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException","message":"Operation category READ is not supported in state standby"}}
```

Comment: Hi.. Do you know how to connect to the NameNode JMX with Kerberos enabled? We ran the kinit before the curl command. But we got a could not connect error

Comment: Perhaps http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-3-2/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_7_2.html can help you?

Answer (score 8):

In a High Availability Hadoop cluster, there will be 2 namenodes - one active and one standby.

To find the active namenode, we can try executing the test hdfs command on each of the namenodes and find the active name node corresponding to the successful run.

Below command executes successfully if the name node is active and fails if it is a standby node.

```
hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://<Name node>/
```

**Unix script**

```
active_node=''
if hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://<NameNode-1>/ ; then
active_node='<NameNode-1>'
elif hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://<NameNode-2>/ ; then
active_node='<NameNode-2>'
fi

echo "Active Dev Name node : $active_node"
```

Comment: this is most simplest one. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in bash with hdfs cli calls, too. With the noted caveat that this takes a bit more time since it's a few calls to the API in succession, but this may be preferable to using a python script for some.

This was tested with Hadoop 2.6.0

```
get_active_nn(){
   ha_name=$1 #Needs the NameServiceID
   ha_ns_nodes=$(hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.ha.namenodes.${ha_name})
   active=""
   for node in $(echo ${ha_ns_nodes//,/ }); do
     state=$(hdfs haadmin -getServiceState $node)
     if [ "$state" == "active" ]; then
       active=$(hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.namenode.rpc-address.${ha_name}.${node})
       break
     fi
   done
   if [ -z "$active" ]; then
     >&2 echo "ERROR: no active namenode found for ${ha_name}"
     exit 1
   else
     echo $active
   fi
}
```

Comment: How about programmatically (java, scala anything ) but using only api calls.

Comment: try HAUtil.getAddressOfActive(FileSystem fs)

Answer (score 3):

After reading all the existing answers none seemed to combine the three steps of:

1. Identifying the namenodes from the cluster.
2. Resolving the node names to host:port.
3. Checking the status of each node (without requiring
   cluster admin privs).

Solution below combines `hdfs getconf` calls and JMX service call for node status.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import check_output
import urllib, json, sys

def get_name_nodes(clusterName):
    ha_ns_nodes=check_output(['hdfs', 'getconf', '-confKey',
        'dfs.ha.namenodes.' + clusterName])
    nodes = ha_ns_nodes.strip().split(',')
    nodeHosts = []
    for n in nodes:
        nodeHosts.append(get_node_hostport(clusterName, n))

    return nodeHosts

def get_node_hostport(clusterName, nodename):
    hostPort=check_output(
        ['hdfs','getconf','-confKey',
         'dfs.namenode.rpc-address.{0}.{1}'.format(clusterName, nodename)])
    return hostPort.strip()

def is_node_active(nn):
    jmxPort = 50070
    host, port = nn.split(':')
    url = "http://{0}:{1}/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus".format(
            host, jmxPort)
    nnstatus = urllib.urlopen(url)
    parsed = json.load(nnstatus)

    return parsed.get('beans', [{}])[0].get('State', '') == 'active'

def get_active_namenode(clusterName):
    for n in get_name_nodes(clusterName):
        if is_node_active(n):
            return n

clusterName = (sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None)
if not clusterName:
    raise Exception("Specify cluster name.")

print 'Cluster: {0}'.format(clusterName)
print "Nodes: {0}".format(get_name_nodes(clusterName))
print "Active Name Node: {0}".format(get_active_namenode(clusterName))
```

Answer (score 2):

From java api, you can use `HAUtil.getAddressOfActive(fileSystem)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a curl command to find out the Active and secondary Namenode 
for example

> curl -u username -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET
>   http://cluster-hostname:8080/api/v1/clusters//services/HDFS

Regards

Comment: is the X-Requested-By required?

Answer (score 1):

I found the below when i simply typed 'hdfs' and found a couple of helpful commands, which could be useful for someone who could maybe come here seeking for help.

```
hdfs getconf -namenodes
```

This above command will give you the service id of the namenode. Say, **hn1.hadoop.com**

```
hdfs getconf -secondaryNameNodes
```

This above command will give you the service id of the available secondary namenodes. Say , **hn2.hadoop.com**

```
hdfs getconf -backupNodes
```

This above command will get you the service id of backup nodes, if any.

```
hdfs getconf -nnRpcAddresses
```

This above command will give you info of name service id along with rpc port number. Say, **hn1.hadoop.com:8020**

```
                                  You're Welcome :)
```

Comment: This is an excellent post with a wealth of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

In HDFS 2.6.0 the one that worked for me

```
ubuntu@platform2:~$ hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.ha.namenodes.arkin-platform-cluster
nn1,nn2
ubuntu@platform2:~$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn1
standby
ubuntu@platform2:~$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn2
active
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the below command. I have tested this in hadoop 3.0 You can check the reference [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#haadmin) -

> hdfs haadmin -getAllServiceState

It returns the state of all the NameNodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of bash code that returns active name node even if you do not have local hadoop installation.
It also works faster as **curl** calls are usually faster than **hadoop**.
Checked on Cloudera 7.1

```
#!/bin/bash
export nameNode1=myNameNode1
export nameNode2=myNameNode2
active_node=''
T1=`curl --silent --insecure  -request GET https://${nameNode1}:9871/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus | grep "\"State\" : \"active\"" | wc -l`
if [ $T1 == 1 ]
then
    active_node=${nameNode1}
else
    T1=`curl --silent --insecure  -request GET https://${nameNode2}:9871/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus | grep "\"State\" : \"active\"" | wc -l`
    if [ $T1 == 1 ]
    then
        active_node=${nameNode2}
    fi
fi

echo "Active Dev Name node : $active_node"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys
import os, errno


def getActiveNameNode () :

    cmd_string="hdfs getconf -namenodes"
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_string, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    NameNodes = out
    Value = NameNodes.split(" ")
    for val in Value :
        cmd_str="hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://"+val
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_str, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = process.communicate()
        if (err != "") :
            return val

def main():

    out = getActiveNameNode()
    print(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for this answer. It would be helpful if you could explain the code so people know how and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

`more /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml`

```xml
<property>
  <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.nameservice1</name>
  <value>namenode1353,namenode1357</value>
 </property>
```

```sh
hdfs@:/home/ubuntu$  hdfs haadmin -getServiceState  namenode1353
active 
hdfs@:/home/ubuntu$  hdfs haadmin -getServiceState  namenode1357
standby
```