# hdfs dfs -ls on remote file system with multiple name nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We have two namenodes: nnA and nnB.

From a remote system I want to see files and directories of this system.

If nnA is the primary namenode I can do hdfs dfs -Dfs.defaultFS=hdfs://nnA -ls /path/to/files
If nnB is the primary namenode I can do hdfs dfs -Dfs.defaultFS=hdfs://nnB -ls /path/to/files

Both of these commands work fine if the namenode I'm using happens to be the primary at the time. If the namenode I choose to use happens to be the secondary namenode I get the error `Operation category READ is not supported in state standby.`

I want to be able to specify both namenodes in my command. From the remote system I have no way of knowing which namenode is the primary and which is the secondary and its entirely possible for them to switch occasionally.

This is for a script I'm working on and I really want to avoid looping through possible primary namenodes any time I do a call to hdfs.

I've spent all day googling and haven't found a solution or anyone else with this use case

Comment: just found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6376 which was exactly what i needed. just need to configure the nameservice for the remote cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the remote system I have no way of knowing which namenode is the primary and which is the secondary

First, "secondary namenode" actually means something, and it seems like you meant **standby** namenode instead, based on the error you get.

[You need to refer to the `dfs.nameservices`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html) in your `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hdfs-site.xml`, then you can use `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://nameservice/path`

Related - [Any command to get active namenode for nameservice in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648214/any-command-to-get-active-namenode-for-nameservice-in-hadoop#26664248)

Comment: it appears i need to first configure a nameservice for the remote namenodes, then referencing the name service should work.