# Create flag in HDFS that represent the active namenode in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I just wondering , if somewhere in `HDFS` , we can find some signature file that help us to know which is the active name-node ?

if not we can create a flag as file in `HDFS` , and this flag will get the active name-node machine , for example by the following API that will runs from Linux Cron Job each min

```
> curl 'http://172.20.11.177:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'
{
  "beans" : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
    "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
    "State" : "active",
    "NNRole" : "NameNode",
    "HostAndPort" : "localhost:19000",
    "SecurityEnabled" : false,
    "LastHATransitionTime" : 0
  } ]

# "State" is "initializing", "active", "standby" or "stopping".
# "LastHATransitionTime" is the last time of the last flip from standby to active (or vice versa)
```

Reference - [Any command to get active namenode for nameservice in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648214/any-command-to-get-active-namenode-for-nameservice-in-hadoop)

**the goal is:**

we run Thousands executes a cross 540 nodes ( node managers machines )
each executor ask by `http` request which is the active name-node

asking so many requests across on Hadoop cluster isn't so elegant and maybe cause performance issue or maybe other collisions

so we thinking about to create some file as flag in `HDFS` that include the name of the active name-node

but it will be excellent if this file already created somewhere ? as part of entire `HDFS` structure

Comment: 1) The information should be in [Zookeeper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html#Initializing_HA_state_in_ZooKeeper), if you use QJM 2) Rather than use Jolokia, you could use Prometheus JMX exporter, then query _Prometheus Server_ instead. That would reduce the HTTP load on the namenode.

Comment: how to know if we use - QJM

Comment: The link describes how to set it up, so look at your hdfs XML config files and compare the settings

Comment: @jessica, Ignore my understanding. Why do you run http request? Is it to find out which one is active?